# SQL count and group by based on values

Tags: sql, count

Here is my source data:

```
Point | Status

P1    |  caution

P1    |  normal

P1    |  normal

P2    |  caution

P2    |  caution

P2    |  caution
```

I'm trying to write a query that will output:

```
P1, caution, 1

P1, normal, 2

P2, caution, 3
```

Comment: did you try count and group by?

Comment: `I'm trying to write a query` what's it look like now?

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be something like the following:

```
SELECT P_COLUMN, STATUS_COLUMN, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY P_COLUMN, STATUS_COLUMN;
```

Since there were no table or column names provided, I made my best guess.

Comment: @Koshera is right in his answer. Not having the STATUS_COLUMN in the group by will throw an error. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

More like:

```
SELECT point, status, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY point, status;
```

The status column needs to be part of the group by clause. Otherwise it can't be part of the select statement without an aggregate function...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help!  I got it another way too:

> SELECT
>    Point,
>
> SUM(CASE WHEN Status=Normal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Normal,
>
> SUM(CASE WHEN Status=Cation THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Caution
>
> FROM 
>      Table
>
> GROUP BY 
>      Point